# How to create Object in realm

Tags: android, realm

I have this code, what sgould I write instead of question marks '???'

Token is my class in project with fields name and tokenValue

```
String tokenString = response.getString("token");
mRealm.beginTransaction();

Token myToken = mRealm.createObject( ??? );
myToken.name = "token";
myToken.tokenValue = tokenString;

mRealm.commitTransaction();
```

=======================================
I have this error:
error: no suitable method found for createObject(Class)
                   Token myToken = mRealm.createObject(myToken.getClass());
                                         ^
    method Realm.createObject(Class) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: CAP#1
        upper bound(s): RealmModel)

Comment: I assume Token does not extend RealmObject, or implement RealmModel?

Comment: no, it does not

Comment: may I ask why not? If you spend 3 seconds reading the docs, it's pretty obvious you need one of the 2

Comment: I declared my class as  public class Token extends RealmObject{
    String name;
    String tokenValue;
}                                   though in line 'Token myToken = mRealm.createObject(Token.getRealm()); '      I still have this error:  non-static method getRealm() cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use realm like this,

```
public class University extends RealmObject {
    @Index
    private int id;
    private String name;
// getters & setters 
}

Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
realm.beginTransaction();
University university = realm.createObject(University.class); // Create a new object
user.setName("John");
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: thanks, this is example from the Internet. I just want to implememt this in my own application.

Comment: Yes, You can take reference from this.Token myToken = mRealm.createObject(Token.class);

Comment: Token.class - this was helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If its helps to you, Accept the answer if you wish

Answer (score 0):

check the latest docs [Realm Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

```
// Get a Realm instance for this thread
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

Create the models like that

```
public class User extends RealmObject {

private String          name;
private int             age;

@Ignore
private int             sessionId;

// Standard getters & setters generated by your IDE…
public String getName() { return name; }
public void   setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
public int    getAge() { return age; }
public void   setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
public int    getSessionId() { return sessionId; }
public void   setSessionId(int sessionId) { this.sessionId = sessionId; }
}
```

add object through class

```
realm.beginTranscation();

User user=realm.createObject(user.class);
    user.name = "Fido";
    user.age  = 5;

realm.commitTranscation();
```

and you can directly create object from json

```
realm.beginTranscation();

User user=realm. createObjectFromJson(user.class,{"jsonfields":"sample"});

realm.commitTranscation();
```